# $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $c\equiv d \pmod n$ implies $ac \equiv bd \pmod n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Given that $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $c\equiv d \pmod n$, I need to prove that $ac \equiv bd \pmod n$

So far, I've only managed to deduce that $a+b \equiv c+d \pmod n$. I don't know if this is usable, but it's there, at least.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @DonAntonio - You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
{\bf Hint}\ \ \ a\ &=\  \color{#c00}b\ \ +\,n\,j\\
 c\, &= \ \  \color{#0a0}d\,+\,n\,k\\
\Longrightarrow\,\ ac &= \color{#c00}b\color{#0a0}d\,+\,n\:\!(\ldots)\ \ \text{for an } {\it integer} \ (\ldots)
\end{align}$

**Remark** $\, $ If $\,n = 10\,$ then this generalizes a units digit rule well-known from decimal arithmetic, namely mod $10,\,$ the units digit of a product is congruent to the product of the unit digits, e.g. $\,1\color{#c00}3\cdot 1\color{#0a0}6 = 208\,$ has units digit $\,\color{#c00}3\cdot\color{#0a0}6\equiv 8.\,$ Said in the language of the  [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\ 10\!:\ &&1\color{#00}{3}\equiv \color{#c00}3,\ \ 1\color{0a0}{6}\equiv \color{#0a0}6\\[.2em]
\Longrightarrow\ &&1\color{c00}{3}\cdot 1\color{0a0}{6}\equiv \color{#c00}3\cdot \color{#0a0}6\equiv 8\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad  $$

We can view the Congruence Product Rule as a radix $\,n\,$ generalization of the units digit product rule. However, it is more general, since  the "units digits" $\,\color{#c00}b,\color{#0a0}d\,$ need not lie in the interval $\,[0,n\!-\!1].$

The prior linked post has proofs of all of the common congruence arithmetic rules.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$ac-bd=ac-ad+ad-bd=a(c-d)+d(a-b)=\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it out. Took me a few minutes to recognize where you were going with it, but that just defines a good hint. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like Gauss did in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*:
$$
a\equiv b\pmod{n}
$$
implies
$$
ak\equiv bk\pmod{n}
$$
for all $k$.

Suppose now $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{n}$. Then
$$
ac\equiv bc\pmod{n}
$$
and
$$
bc\equiv bd\pmod{n}.
$$
By transitivity,
$$
ac\equiv bd\pmod{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

a ≡ b (mod n) means a = b + xn for some x. Work with that definition.

Comment: For some *integer* $\;x\;$ ...